# Get qty from json

Tags: php, arrays, json

noob here! How I can get 'qty' value to print only 0 with json and php from:

```
{"XXXXXX":[],"XXXXXX":[],"total":[{"assetref":"","qty":0,"raw":0}]}
```

I've tried this

```
$m = json_encode('{"XXXXXX":[],"XXXXXX":[],"total":[{"assetref":"","qty":0,"raw":0}]}')
$multi = json_decode($m, true);
echo $multi->{'qty'};
```

And not work

Comment: .. var dump $multi and you'll see why doing what you're doing is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have JSON string hence you must not use `json_encode`:

```
$multi = json_decode('{"XXXXXX":[],"XXXXXX":[],"total":[{"assetref":"","qty":0,"raw":0}]}', true);
echo $multi['total'][0]['qty'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` is used to create a JSON string from a variable.

You already have a JSON string so instead of using `$m = json_encode(json_string)` you could simply say that `$m = json_string`.

Also you are missing one level of depth (no reference to `total`) while trying to access the `qty` variable.

(Please notice that `total` is an array which contains one object, which then contains `qty`)

Try that:

```
$m = '{"XXXXXX":[],"XXXXXX":[],"total":[{"assetref":"","qty":0,"raw":0}]}';
$multi = json_decode($m, true);
echo $multi['total'][0]['qty'];
```

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) encodes a array into a string, you're trying to encode a string.

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) on your string so it converts to array.

```
$m = json_decode('{"XXXXXX":[],"XXXXXX":[],"total":[{"assetref":"","qty":10,"raw":0}]}');
$qty = $m->total[0]->qty;
echo $qty;
```